# Converting Image to Base64 string. Loss of Exif Metadata?

Tags: java

Hi so I have been working at this for a few days and i'm wondering if the way I am converting the images on the device is causing a loss of the metadata?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                        
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);         
encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Is what I have to encode the image before it uploads to the database. Am I doing something that would cause the image to lose the metadata? In particular the date of image creation? I have read that using Java.io can cause this but I am unsure of another approach to take.

Any help hints pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What dow you mean by metadata (image, resolution, localosiation, brand, ..) or creation/modification of the image file ?

Comment: hey, so date created, camera type used, filetype etc

Comment: I'd be astonished if the base64 part was the lossy part here. Have you tried saving directly to disk with `bm.compress` and checking that?

Comment: How are you reading your image(s)? Please can you update your question to include this.

Comment: @Jon Currently working through that now thanks